# exclude subdocuments from nested array using single query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that contains docs of following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547b4b4ba7d3aef3bdbc5e1c"),
    "title" : "article1",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "text" : "first comment",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-30T16:52:24.032Z")
        }
    ],
    "pictures" : [
        {
            "url" : "http://example.com/1.jpg",
            "isPrimary" : false
        },
        {
            "url" : "http:example.com/2.jpg",
            "isPrimary" : true
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://example.com/3.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to pull all documents and exclude non-primary pictures using single query. I.e. output should be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547b4b4ba7d3aef3bdbc5e1c"),
    "title" : "article1",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "text" : "first comment",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-11-30T16:52:24.032Z")
        }
    ],
    "pictures" : [
        {
            "url" : "http:example.com/2.jpg",
            "isPrimary" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Or even better if "pictures" will contains document instead of array:

```
...
"pictures" : {
    "url" : "http:example.com/2.jpg",
    "isPrimary" : true
}
...
```

I tried aggregate and $redact, but it doesn't work because the document and the comments sub-doc don't have 'isPrimary' field.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$unwind` in [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
 { $project: {
     _id: 1,
     title: 1,
     comments: 1,
     pictures:  { 
         $cond : [ 
            // if pictures is null or does not exists, project it to []
            {  $eq : [ { $ifNull: [ "$pictures", [] ] } , [] ] },
            // if pictures is [] then project it to a list with one fake empty picture with isPrimary set to true 
            [  { isPrimary: true, _empty: true }  ], 
            // otherwise project it to just the original pictures property
            "$pictures"
         ] } 
 } },
 { $unwind: "$pictures" },
 { $match: { "pictures.isPrimary": true } },
 { $group: {
     _id: "$_id",
     title: { $first: "$title" },
     comments: { $first: "$comments" },
     picture: { $first: "$pictures" }
 } },
 { $project: {
    _id: 1,
     title: 1,
     comments: 1,
     // filter out the fake isPrimary pictures that were added in the initial projection
     picture: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$picture._empty", true ] }, {}, "$picture" ] }
 } }
])
```

Comment: If pictures is empty array then such articles won't be pulled.

Comment: In our logic we're assuming elements with empty `pictures` actually have one `isPrimary` picture for `$unwind` to work. We remove this fake `isPrimary` picture at the end of the query.